# Block questions containing lots of <br> tags

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Some new users who don't know how to format code tend to put a `<br/>` linebreak after every code line. This makes it extremely annoying for others to fix their formatting.

I don't think there's a good reason why anyone would use many `<br/>` tags outside of indented code. So why not disallow posting such a question? Or at least suggest to format it properly.

Comment: Or: downvote such user's post, post a comment to refer them to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (or to balpha's [nap sack](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635) example, to explain paragraphs), and remove the downvote when they have fixed it themselves?

Comment: I do not think this is a good idea. Sometimes, <br/> are really useful, and not everybody like markdown

Comment: it would be better to replace them with two spaces, like markdown

Comment: @örs, are you saying that the editor should change HTML into Markdown before saving it? (We're not even [converting tabs to spaces in the source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90901/automatically-convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-the-original-text), and HTML [is perfectly accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79996/is-it-ok-to-use-html-formatting-in-all-my-posts-rather-than-markdown/80055#80055) here.)

Comment: @arjan oh :D forgot about html questions, that would be cruel :D

Comment: Well, if a low-rep user posts HTML it's likely that he just doesn't know how to do it properly...

Comment: I'm personally _thrilled_ about the new "give a reason why you're rejecting this edit" dialog box for rejecting edit suggestions -- I can finally say "please use markdown formatting instead". Of course, it doesn't help much for _initial_ questions, but if someone went to some effort to format their question nicely, hooray. Too many ugly ones already.

Comment: Sure, it might be a minor annoyance, but can't a search-and-replace fix it rather quickly?

Comment: @icktoofay: Browsers do not support search-and-replace so I have to copy it to an editor first.-