# quick edit tool box

Tags: feature-request, edits, automation

### Abstract

We all, the ones who edit questions or answers, go through questions to implement the same edits to every question that needs an edit. Which is just an unneeded repetition that can be simply solved by having a quick edit panel for the most used edits. Of-course some questions need human interaction, I guess, to be edited. But for the most part I believe that more than 80% of the questions that are edited go though the same editing routine.

### What are the most common edits that a question/answer editor do?!

I have went ahead and created a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) asking about that, which can be used as a further reference.

For my part I find these are the most common ones:

- Replace `i` with `I`.
- Right click then pick the first spelling mistake suggestion.
- Re-upload images for users that don't have enough privilege.
- Insert proper line brakes. (Some people just insert one line break)
- Format the code in a code-sample.
- Format function names as code, so it stands out from the rest of the text. e.g. "I use this function `bla()`."
- Capitalize the first letter. This can be easily achieved if the user uses some punctuation marks.
- <del>Separate text into paragraphs, usually where there is a dot.</del>

### Will this be 100% accurate all the time?

This feature will only be triggered by a human. So if any thing goes wrong he can still go into manual-mode.
While this can't be accurate all the time. It still can help a lot and can reduce the amount of tedious work.

Comment: While this would mostly work there are edge cases, the variable i or specialic terms of errors that are uncapitalised. And if course there is a very good reason for a human in the loop for photo insertions

Comment: The only part that can be automated is replacing "i" with "I" but then again, what about code? In C# for example it will ruin most loops. All in all, those things can't be reliably automated and there are more than enough users to gladly edit and review edits.

Comment: @RichardTingle this feature will be triggered by human , who will revise what has been done . thats why he still get the edit points

Comment: How do you know if an "i" should be converted to "I", or to "`i`" (i.e. put in code tags)? Or even $i$ to use tex formatting?

Comment: By the way "For my part i find these are the most common one... Replace `i` with `I`" - priceless.

Comment: what I meant is that an " i " (out side the code ) should be converted to an " I " (out side the code) . sorry but I though it is obvious that I'm talking about text only

Comment: The autoconverter could remove spaces to the left of punctuation marks ;)

Comment: @codeiz many times users do not put code blocks.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and many times i said that this will be triggered by human . he can see whats happening , this will only help .

Comment: If you haven't said it in the question then you haven't said it at all

Comment: @RichardTingle ` a quick edit panel for the most used edits.` it's a panel which a user must use . that's what I though at least . but any how I have edited the question to explicit .

Comment: I like my spaces around dashes @CodesInChaos - they're important to me :-(.

Comment: That's fine . But do you like them around periods , commas or question marks ?

Comment: Now that its less "auto" and more "tool box" i'm coming around to it, but I can guarantee we'll get more mad edits comimg through the suggestion edits where people have ticked everything and then submitted without actually checking it

Comment: @RichardTingle hmm, while I agree with you. still this will do more help than harm , as far as I can imagine .

Comment: I think I am comimg down on your side and have +1ed this but I think what this proposal needs is a mock up of how the dialogue would fit in with the edit screen

Comment: "Separate text into paragraphs, usually where there is a dot." Holy hell! I only just noticed this one! I usually edit the other way, to remove the one sentence paragraphs

Comment: Maybe the concrete examples aren't ideal, but in general a concept of such a toolbox seems like a good idea. Converting TABS to spaces could prove very useful IMHO.

Comment: @codeiz I see now, fair enough. -1 undone but still don't think we really need such a thing. I think you can achieve some with user scripts though. :)

Answer (score 8):

> Replace i with I.

It's been suggested before - [Can 'u' and 'i' part ways with Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105180/can-u-and-i-part-ways-with-stack-exchange) (and if done sensitively would be 'mazing).

> Right click then pick the first spelling mistake suggestion.

????

> Re-upload images for users that don't have enough privilege.

I guess that might work; you'd have to be careful the users weren't just using a URL that could be a picture as an example of what they're trying to achieve...

> Insert proper line brakes. (Some people just insert one line break)

There is absolutely no way you're going to get this correct... ever.

> Format the code in a code-sample.

Determining what is code is nigh on impossible. Is KTHXBYE code or not?

> Format function names as code, so it stands out from the rest of the text. e.g. "I use this function bla()."

I guess you're implying here that anything that matches the pattern `\w+\(\)` should be enclosed in backticks if it's not already? This doesn't actually annoy me that much, though I'll normally do it if I'm editing something else.

> Capitalize the first letter. This can be easily achieved if the user uses some punctuation marks.

*i is my index variable but its not working* (or summat())

> Separate text into paragraphs, usually where there is a dot.

I really don't want every sentence to be a paragraph.

It will get really, really annoying.

Because people put full-stops in weird places and I'd have to go and undo it.

all.

---

I'm by no means against aided (rather than automated) editing of posts, but it's one of those areas that it's extremely difficult to do correctly. It doesn't take *that* long (unless the ******* has put [`<br>` instead of linebreaks everywhere.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116316/block-questions-containing-lots-of-br-tags))

Comment: regarding the `Insert proper line brakes. (Some people just insert one line break)` what i meant is that when you use the editor and you want to make a sentence in a new paragraph you have to enter a double line break . some new users will just hit enter once . which will reflect nothing on the formatting .

Comment: @codeiz What if that is what they want?

Comment: if you figured that they don't want to have the line break then just don't put it  . the editor is still there . and he is in full control over whats happening .

Comment: By "right click and choose first suggestion" he means [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l9IPk.png). @codeiz FYI it will lead to certain odd stuff much like the infamous auto correction in cellular phone text messages. You really don't want that but no worry, I doubt it's technically possible since it's internal browser behavior.